# Where can I find header files in C on unix

Tags: c, unix, header-files

Where can I find my C header files on unixOS.Please kindly give me your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers requested with #include  in:

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```